# is local storage capable of storing large size data?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a progressive web app with react js that a user can download multiple magazines but these magazines have not to be downloaded in his phone so he can not be able to share them with others. So my idea is to stock these magazines in local storage. 
The problem is only one magazine can have a size of 50mb and more.
I found that local storage can stock to 10mb per object so I maybe decompose a magazine in multiple objects but I felt that it's not an ideal solution and local storage are not made to store these size of data.
So my question is putting large data in local storage will affect the app performance ? and what you advice me to do in my situation.
I am really stuck guys. thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large data storage, use Indexeddb. Check the [localForage](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/) library by mozilla, which uses Indexddb (with WebSQL and localStorage fallbacks depending on the browser support).

Comment: thank you jorbuedo for your reply it's a better solution then local storage ! does putting big sized data in localForge affect the app performance ?

Comment: It should not affect performance, besides the obvious read/write times.